# Intermittant SMTP email exception - Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server response was: 4.4.2 service timed out

Tags: smtp

I have started to see an intermittant error when sending email via my application.

> System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server response was: 4.4.2 service timed out.

Now obviously it's timing out for some reason, but any ideas as to why this is happening now? This is the first time I've seen it happen.

Comment: According to [stackoverflow.com/q/17933863](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17933863), it may be the _receiver_ mail server that is blacklisting the sender. ([Frank Shmitt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5868645/780703) below indicates app admin's filter.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things to check:

- has anything on the server side changed? Did the admins add some kind of greylisting, perhaps?
- what happens if you connect to the server directly via telnet on port 25?
- does this occur from other applications, as well (e.g. your desktop E-mail client) ?

Comment: I've got an email into support, but it's intermittant, so don't think my app server has been greylisted. 2) can't, everything is very locked down, 3) not that I'm aware of. Thanks!

Comment: There might also be some kind of spam prevention system at work. If your application sends too many E-Mails in a short period of time, the server might switch to some kind of tar pit mode (since it thinks you are a spammer).

Comment: the app certainly does send anything like as much as should trigger spam detection like that, but that may well be the issue, if so I'll get support to tweak the numbers! thanks again Frank!